# How do I combine TypeScript and C# in a single Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript

We are using Visual Studio to build services that include self-hosting single-page TypeScript applications (basically, HTML UIs).  When a service receives a request for the web UI, it dynamically merges the .html, .css, and .js files in the deployment folder to produce the response for the client.

The structure of each project is a C# console application with the TypeScript and HTML components in a sub-folder.  We have extra rules in the .csproj files to carry out TypeScript builds whenever the rest of the project is built.  We are experiencing two kinds of problem:

- the TypeScript compiler sees every .ts file in the entire solution is somehow in scope, rather than just the .ts files in the project itself, leading to hundreds of spurious duplicate definition errors;
- we want the generated .js files to be output to the deployment folder (build or debug, accordingly).  I've tried including the generated .js files as part of the project (ugh) and setting them to 'Copy Always', but this leads to problems since Visual Studio then thinks the build step is overwriting a source file!

I've experimented with tsconfig.json files, but to no avail.  If anyone could explain in simple terms what is needed, that would be magic!

Comment: You'll need a `tsconfig.json` file in *each directory* containing the files to be compiled. This file defines the root of a typescript project. Then, you'd invoke `tsc -p '/path/to/tsproject/'`. Alternatively, you'll need to grab the files to be compiled and pass them to `tsc` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response.  Is it sufficient to simply list '"files":["MyTopLevel.ts"]' in the tsconfig.json file?

Comment: That *should* be enough to satisfy the compiler - assuming `MyTopLevel.ts` doesn't have any dependencies.

Comment: I've been listing dependencies explicitly in the .ts files via the old /// <reference...> mechanism.